# Как отправить форму ajax php на почту

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

Доброе время суток. Есть сайт, на нем есть форма. С помощью ajax беру из нее данные и отправляю в php, который лежит на другом сайте. Проверка выводит в консоли, что данные отправлены. В php с помощью phpmailer отправляется сообщение. СМТП, адреса, пароль, все верно, но сообщения нет.
По разному все пробовал, но так и не отправляет, не знаю почему.

```
 $(function() {
  $('form').submit(function(e) {
    var $form = $(this);
    $.ajax({
      type: $form.attr('method'),
      url: $form.attr('action'),
      data: $form.serialize()
    }).done(function() {
      console.log('success');
    }).fail(function() {
      console.log('fail');
    });
    e.preventDefault(); 
  });
});

<?php
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\Exception;
// Файлы phpmailer
require 'PHPMailer.php';
require 'SMTP.php';
require 'Exception.php';

// Переменные, которые отправляет пользователь
$name = $_POST['name'];
$tel = isset($_POST['tel']);
$radio = isset($_POST['radio-group']);
echo $name;
$mail = new PHPMailer();
try {
    $msg = "ok";
    $mail->isSMTP();   
    $mail->CharSet = "UTF-8";                                          
    $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;

    // Настройки вашей почты
    $mail->Host       = 'smtp.mail.ru'; // SMTP сервера GMAIL
    $mail->Username   = 'login'; // Логин на почте
    $mail->Password   = 'password'; // Пароль на почте
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';
    $mail->Port       = 465;
    $mail->setFrom('email1', 'YOUR NAME'); // Адрес самой почты и имя отправителя

    // Получатель письма
    $mail->addAddress('email2');  
        // -----------------------
        // Само письмо
        // -----------------------
        $mail->isHTML(true);

        $mail->Subject = 'Заголовок письма';
        $mail->Body    = "<b>Имя:</b> $name <br>
        <b>Почта:</b> $tel<br><br>
        <b>Сообщение:</b><br>$radio";    
// Проверяем отправленность сообщения
if ($mail->send()) {
    echo "$msg";
} else {
echo "Сообщение не было отправлено. Неверно указаны настройки вашей почты";
}
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo "Сообщение не было отправлено. Причина ошибки: {$mail->ErrorInfo}";
}
?>
```

Comment: Нужны ли тут `$mail = new PHPMailer();` скобки?

Comment: для отладки не плохо было бы включить дэбаг $mail->SMTPDebug = SMTP::DEBUG_LOWLEVEL;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

вместо $mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';
попробуйте так:

```
$mail->SMTPOptions = array(
            'ssl' => array(
                'verify_peer' => false,
                'verify_peer_name' => false,
                'allow_self_signed' => true
            )
        );
```

Comment: Спасибо, после этого начал отправлять

Comment: К сожалению 1 раз отправил и все

Comment: Включите отладку на уровне сервер клиент. Покажите что происходит.

Comment: Вообще не знаю как это сделать